Git changes related
I installed the Github Copilot update on my PyCharm 2024.2.1 (Community Edition).
When I restarted the IDE, I couldn't find the changes I made to the code in the Commit section nor can I see the remote/and local branches.
What do I do?
I don't want to the loose the changes I've made, I could just clone the remote repo elsewhere and copy the changes, which I want to do as a last resort. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this but I'd like help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
